# Cython pyximport error on Windows

Tags: mingw, cython

I'm making my first steps with Cython, and I've installed it on my machine according to the [instructions](http://wiki.cython.org/InstallingOnWindows) in the wiki.

Working through the Cython tutorial I got to [pyximport](http://docs.cython.org/docs/tutorial.html#pyximport-cython-compilation-the-easy-way), which is supposed to make cython compilation really simple. When I tried using it, though, I got the following error message (reformatted):

```
ImportError: Building module failed: 
DistutilsPlatformError('
    Python was built with Visual Studio 2003;
    extensions must be built with a compiler than can generate compatible binaries.
    Visual Studio 2003 was not found on this system. If you have Cygwin installed,
    you can try compiling with MingW32, by passing "-c mingw32" to setup.py.',)
```

So my question is: anyone know of a way to make pyximport use mingw?

Note that mingw seems to be installed properly, the long way to make Cython modules (using setup.py) *did* work for me, and that I even created a `distutils.cfg` file like the wiki told me.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you. I'm running Python 2.6 with Cython and I just gritted my teeth and downloaded the free VS 2008 kit from MS (only a coupla terrorbites) and it just worked. You might not have to wait 5 months for an answer if you (a) supply basic details like what version of Python, what version & SP of Windows you have, what version of mingw you have, and the minimum bare code needed to demonstrate the problem and (b) like I would, ask on the Cython support list.

Answer (score 13):

I was recently mucking around and discovered the setup_args argument of pyximport.install.  This works for me:

```
mingw_setup_args={'options': {'build_ext': {'compiler': 'mingw32'}}}
import pyximport; pyximport.install(setup_args=mingw_setup_args)
```

Answer (score 10):

[maybe this way (from mail list)](http://groups.google.com/group/cython-users/browse_thread/thread/f6b4dea016a984de):

c:\Python2x\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg:

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32

[build_ext]
compiler = mingw32
```

Comment: Thanks! I had only `[build]` in my cfg file and couldn't figure out what was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a "**pydistutils.cfg**" file under your home so that you get either of those paths:
"**C:\Documents and Settings\YourUsername\pydistutils.cfg**" or "**C:\Users\YourUsername\pydistutils.cfg**".

Then add:

**[build_ext]**

**compiler=mingw32**

to that file. Also make sure you have **"MinGW"**'s gcc on your path.
From that point on, when you use "import pyximport; pyximport.install()",
cython should generate a folder named ".pyxbld" under your home folder(See Above).
On windows, this folder will contain all of the " **.c, .o, .pyd, .def**" files generated by cython.

Happy cythoning!