# Modules compiled with /openmp cannot be import?

Tags: python, python-2.7, openmp, cython

I have a very simple cython code which use `prange`, which works fine in linux. However, when I try to do it in Windows. I encountered a problem that it can be compiled but cannot be imported:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: This application has failed to start because the a
pplication configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this
problem.
```

Moreover, in windows I cannot `from cython.parallel import threadlocal`?! strange...

Is there anyone can point a direction?

System works fine: **linux64**, compiler **gcc**, packages: **Python 2.7, cython 0.16**

system has problem: **Win64**, compiler: **MSVC VS2008**, packages: **Python 2.7, cython 0.16**

Here is my simple cython pyx:

```
cimport cython
from cython.parallel import prange

def f(int n):
    cdef int i
    cdef int sum = 0
    for i in prange(n, nogil=True):
        sum += i
    print sum
```

Here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np


setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    include_dirs = [np.get_include()], 
    ext_modules = [Extension("pcython1",  ["pcython1.pyx"],extra_compile_args=['/openmp',],),]
)
```

Comment: Does the code work fine under windows if prange is replaced by range?

Comment: @DaveP Thanks for your response!
Without `/openmp`, both `range` and `prange` work. With it, neither of them works.

Comment: Turns out if the system has not installed the `MS visual studio` but only the `VC++ redustributable`, it works fine... Confused... And the CPU loads are completely different between `range` and `prange` version. So the openMP is working, just it cannot work on the system with the debug dlls installed, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the VS2008 installer bug, the amd64_microsoft.vc90.openMP does not get installed into winSxS. Installing the openMP runtime will solve this problem.

see this question for detail: [How to properly setup VS2008 for x64 programing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217174/how-to-properly-setup-vs2008-for-x64-programing/13222870#13222870)

Answer (score 0):

Use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943658/cython-pyximport-error-on-windows) to properly setup mingw with cython) , then update your **setup.py** to:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np

ext_modules = [Extension("convolve_cy", ["convolve_cy.pyx"],
                         extra_compile_args = ["-O3", "-fopenmp"],
                         extra_link_args=["-fopenmp"])]

setup (
    name = 'performance test app',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
    ext_modules = ext_modules,
)
```

This is working on a windows7 multi-core 64bit machine with Python 2.7 and cython 2.0.